# Remove comma on object property

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get rid of the comma when fetching the object property but i always get it when i fetch the name. This is what i have tried:

```
var items = [{ "id": "1",   "name": "ball" }, { "id": "2", "name": "galaxy" }];

var getName =  items.map(function(element){
        if (element.id == 2){
        return element.name.replace(',', '');
    }
});

alert(getName);
```

And i always get this

[image]

or this

[image]

Here is [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YwtrB/26/)

So how to print out clean name without any commas?

Comment: The names do not contain a comma

Comment: OK, how to print out the variable without comma, just name?

Comment: There is no comma in the values. Your issue is because `map()` creates an array, and you're then coercing that array to a string when you `alert()` it. I'd suggest you do all debugging using `console.log` instead as the type of the variable is immediately obvious there, and it's no always coerced to a string like `alert()` does

Comment: Thank you all, i have learned a lot now....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem results of how `Array#toString()` works: `null` and `undefined` values are turned into empty Strings, and the Array is joined by ",":

```js
var names = [undefined, "galaxy"];

console.log("names (array):", names);
console.log("names (string):", String(names));
```

`alert(names)` forces `names` to be converted to String, because `alert()` can only print strings. Better use the console.

I'm not sure wether you want to print one name or all names, your code is ambigious to me.

```js
var items = [{ "id": "1",   "name": "ball" }, { "id": "2", "name": "galaxy" }];


//since you're using `map` it implies that you want 
//to fetch the name of every item in the array
//because this is what `Array#map()` does.
function getAllNames(){
  return items.map(item => item.name);
}

console.log("all names:", getAllNames(items));

//on the other hand, your condition would imply you want only a specific item
function getNameById(id){
  return items.find(item => item.id === id).name;
}

console.log("name of #1:", getNameById("1"));
console.log("name of #2:", getNameById("2"));
```

And there's another thing. You've named your variable `getName` wich would imply to me that it contains a function that I can execute to get the name. But it does not. It contains an array with names and `undefined` values.

Proper naming of variables and functions helps a lot to understand what's going on in a particular part of the code; not just to us, but also If you have to take another look at that code in two weeks from now.

Comment: I have to say that this is the best answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array#filter()` to filter with the id you need - `Array#map()` to get only the names and `join()` to join the result to display the names

```js
var items = [{ "id": "1",   "name": "ball" }, { "id": "2", "name": "galaxy" }];
var neededId = "1";
console.log(items.filter(i=>i.id===neededId).map(i=>i.name).join(' '));
```

**Explanation of the comma**

You are creating a new array `getName` which will contain 2 values. The name `ball` but also an undefined value. `Array#map()` is iterating over all the array but for the second object with `id=2` you return nothing. Thus it become `undefined`

When using `console.log` you can clearly see the undefined value.

`alert()` will display an empty string instead of `undefined`. That's why you see the comma. It is to separate the 2 strings

```js
var items = [{ "id": "1", "name": "ball" }, { "id": "2", "name": "galaxy" }];

var getName =  items.map(function(element){
  if (element.id == 1){
        return element.name.replace(',', '');
    }
});
console.log(getName);
```

Comment: Thank you, but in your answer i get printed out all names, and i just need the one where id is  a certain number, if you could correct that, your answer is a potential best answer!

Comment: @lewis4u Done !

Comment: @Weedoze, checkout [Array#find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), like in `var name = items.find(function(item){ return item.id === 1 }).name;`.

Comment: @Thomas I know this function but I cannot assume that OP has all objects with different id in his real case

Answer (score 1):

You could filter the result and map only the wanted property, because [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns something for all elements, but you need [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for getting only one result set.

```js
var items = [{ "id": "1",   "name": "ball" }, { "id": "2", "name": "galaxy" }];

var getName =  items.filter(function (element) {
            return element.id !== "2";
        }).map(function(element){
            return element.name;
        }).join(', ');

console.log(getName);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    var items = [{ "id": "1",   "name": "ball" }, { "id": "2", "name": "galaxy" }];

    var getName =  items.map(function(element){
        if (element.id == 1){          
            return element.name.replace(',', '');
        }
    }).join('');

    alert(getName);
```

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/gnanavelr/YwtrB/27/)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var items = [{ "id": "1",   "name": "ball" }, { "id": "2", "name": "galaxy" }];

// map function will return array of data
// from the code below, we will get
// names = ['ball', 'galaxy']
var names = items.map(function(element){
  return element.name;
});

// to print all names without comma,
// simply join each array item with ' '
console.log(names.join(' ')); // print >> ball galaxy

// if you want to select particular name, using find() may be more sense
const ball = items.find(function(item) {
  return item.id === '1';
});

console.log(ball.name); // print >> ball
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var items = [{ "id": "1", "name": "ball" }, { "id": "2", "name": "galaxy" }];

$.each(items, function(e, val) {
 alert(val.name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```